# What's the word for same-length-sided-ness? equilarity? equilaterity? equilateralness?

Tags: geometry, definition

I'm writing a homework for my middle school students, who are helping Inspector Heptagon of Flatland Yard narrow his list of 2D suspects based solely on eye-witness descriptions.

Given the description *"Plane looking fellow, six equal sides, not sure what his angle was"* the obvious conclusion is a regular hexagon, so I drew an equilateral hexagonal lightning bolt to deconstruct their geometric stereotyping:

https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/eR2Gje5t

I'm looking for the correct word to end my description of the Geogebra construction, to say that moving its vertices won't change the lengths of its sides: "... equilateral hexagonal lightning bolt - you can drag the points to change its shape, but not its **equilateralness**"

Comment: Based on how English works, "equilaterality" could be understood, but I would just recommend rewording to something like "can't change the fact that it's equilateral". As an aside, if you haven't spent a lot of time on non-convex polygons then I wonder if the lightning bolt example would not go over well (or at least make them initially assume that convexity forces regularity).

Comment: I suppose the idea is they're supposed to try dragging the points around to see what happens? Points A, B, C, and D seem to be possible to select for moving, but I can only move E or F as a side effect of moving another point. I found nearly-rectangular convex hexagons, almost-paralellograms, bowties, a chevron, a long thin thing with two pointy ends. Do your students bring examples like that back to class when you given them Geogebra links?

Comment: I would simply state that the distance between neighboring vertices is preserved. But think very carefully about what you are doing. Moving the vertices only preserves the length of the edges because this is how the program works. I would simply state that the lightning bolt is another example of a figure which fits the description. If the point has to be made more clearly, then build a wooden replica with bolts and not and display it in the classroom.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I have added a convex hexagon as a second suspect.

Comment: Sounds like a terrific classroom exercise too

Comment: English has "bilateralness" and "unilateralism". (Perhaps "equilateralism" is a mindset the hexagon cannot change?) But I can't help thinking that something like "equilaterity" is better ... noun-ifying the Latin root directly, rather than augmenting the adjectival form. This is a good question for [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com) and/or [Latin.SE](https://latin.stackexchange.com). (Please update here with any good responses.) In the absence of a "right" (orthogonal?) answer, you might double-down on absurdity and call the characteristic something like "equilateraliticiousness".